# TypeScript multi-line code not recognized

Tags: angular, typescript, sublimetext3, visual-studio-code

Please help me with this error when coding with Typescript in Sublime and VS Code. It can only be recognized and correctly display in browser if all `template:` code is in one single line.

```
template:'<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2><div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div><div><label>name: </label>{{hero.name}}</div>',
```

When I try to break it down to serveral lines, the browser cannot display the result as expected.

Below is the full code of what I'm doing:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:'<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2><div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div><div><label>name: </label>{{hero.name}}</div>',
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
    hero = Hero {
        id: 1;
        name: 'Windstorm';
    }   
}
```

This tutorial is from angular.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use backticks when writing multi lines

```
@Component({
    template: `
        //code here
    `
})
```

Use templates with large amounts of HTML.

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: "PATH HERE"
})
```

Hope that helps

Comment: My bad! missed out on that from the tutorial.